# istio: upgrade envoyfilter on istiogateway to new syntax

Tags: kubernetes, lua, istio, envoyproxy

I'm trying to apply some Lua code to only the istio-ingressgateway pod. So basically, I want to run some Lua code for every request that comes into the ingressgateway.

I've been able to get this to work with the old deprecated syntax using the `filters` as show below.

This works on Istio 1.4.6:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: my-filter
  namespace: default
  labels:
     some-labels
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  authn-ns1: enabled
  filters:
  - filterName: envoy.lua
    filterType: HTTP
    listenerMatch:
      listenerType: GATEWAY
      listenerProtocol: HTTP
    filterConfig:
      inlineCode: |
        function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
              request_handle:logDebug("Hello World")
        end
```

However, I haven't been able to get this to work with the new syntax, and I'm a little confused as to how to piece this together. I've tried to merge the examples from the documentation, 
https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/
but haven't had any luck getting this to work.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: my-filter
  namespace: default
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingress-gateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value: # lua filter specification
       name: envoy.lua
       typed_config:
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
         inlineCode: |
           function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
              request_handle:logDebug("Hello World")
           end
```

I haven't found too many examples of the new syntax, and none that apply the filter to the ingress gateway. I do have the gateway deployed, but I'm not using sidecar injection.

Do you know how I might craft an envoyfilter such that I can apply Lua code to every inbound request using the new syntax? Are there any good examples of how to do this using the new syntax? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You want to use it on istio 1.4.6 or istio 1.5.0? Based on [istio documentation](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/change-notes/#traffic-management) envoyfilter was improved in 1.5.0 so it might not work on 1.4.6.

Comment: I'm currently on 1.4.6, but I want to be able to update to 1.5 and generally just use the new filter syntax. From what I've observed, the old filter syntax does not work on istio 1.5, so that's my most pressing interest in upgrading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I have tried on istio 1.5.x, I used the test case  `tests/testdata/networking/envoyfilter-without-service/configs.yaml` and changed the `workload` to `istio: ingressgateway` to match the istio ingressgateway.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: test-lua
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value: # lua filter specification
        name: envoy.lua
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
          inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
              request_handle:logWarn("Hello World")
            end
```

Comment: Thank you @Johan Gielstra.  Does this have to be created in the istio-system namespace, or can I put it in other namespaces?

Comment: It can be in either the workload's namespace or istio-system.  The istio docs mention that Filters are first applied from `istio-system`, then the workload. 

I haven't tested different namespaces much as I was applying my filter to all ingressgateway http traffic versus a specific workload.

FYI I debug/validate the filters by port forwarding port 15000 on the istio-ingressgateway pod, and doing config_dump, if you are using standard ports you'll see your filter added under you listeners `0.0.0.0_443` and `0.0.0.0_80`

Comment: Good to know. Thank you also for your approach to debugging. I've found that to be a challenging aspect of filters, so anything like that helps.